# compare first word of a string array with a string in c

Tags: c, string

I have a string array of lines.

example:-

```
array[0] = "book floor garden bank autumn";
array[1] = "daisy food yatch beach lottery";
char comp[];
```

I need to compare the first word (eg:- book, daisy...etc) from each index with a string (eg:- comp) using `strcmp()` in a loop.

The question is, is there a simple way of retrieving the first word from the string. 
Is it possible with `strtok` or are there any inbuilt methods that can help.
This is a part of my assignment, I just need an example or a suggestion on how it can be done.

Comment: i didnt quite get, what you want to do here?

Comment: `strtok` should be sufficient.

Comment: saru95 trying to retrieve the first word in the array[0] = book floor garden bank autumn, example book

Comment: @hagubear won't strtok break the whole line into separate words? i just need the first word

Comment: @hagubear eg:- strtok(array[0], " ");??

Comment: @user3236549      yeah - so get the first word. you don't need the others, do you?

Comment: no i dont need others

Comment: Please post some proper code and not vague ramblings. Do you have "an string array" or do you have "two string arrays"? OP asks "is there a simple way of retrieving the first word from the string?" Do you mean "the first word from the string array"?

Comment: Does "yatch" rhyme with "batch", or does "yacht" rhyme with "bot"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

strtok is ok for this and you should do something like:

```
#include <string.h>

int i = 0;
char *token;
int different;

while(i < size){
    token = strtok(array[i], " ");
    different = strcmp(word, token);
    if(different){
        //do something
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: so its going to compare all the words right? dont want it to compare all the words, just need the first.

Comment: yes that's what it does it loops through every index and gets the first word

Comment: Thank you very much @Mauricio Trajano that works very well! I know this was very simple but I just couldn't get through.. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char *array[2];
    char comp[] = "daisy";
    int i;

    array[0] = "book floor garden bank autumn";
    array[1] = "daisy food yatch beach lottery";

    for(i=0;i<2;++i){
        char *p = strchr(array[i], ' ');
        if(!p)
            p = strchr(array[i], '\0');
        size_t len = p - array[i];
        char first_word[len+1];
        memcpy(first_word, array[i], len);
        first_word[len]=0;
        if(strcmp(first_word, comp)==0){
            puts("found it!!");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```